# Pipelined function doesn't return a table with errors

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle18c

I need to insert some values into a table from a collection in a procedure, but I'm getting an `ORA-00902: invalid datatype` error.

This is a target table:

```
create table t_test (col01 number, col02 number);
```

I'm defining a type of collection and a pipelined function in a package:

```
create or replace package p_test is 
  type t_num is table of number;
  function rtn(arg_tn t_num) return t_num PIPELINED;
end p_test;
/
create or replace package body p_test is 
  function rtn(arg_tn t_num) return t_num PIPELINED is 
      tn_row number;
    begin 
      for i in arg_tn.first .. arg_tn.last loop
        tn_row := arg_tn(i);
        pipe row(tn_row);
      end loop;
      return;
  end;
end p_test;
```

And this is my PL/SQL procedure:

```
declare
  tn_test p_test.t_num := p_test.t_num(10,20,30);
  n_num number := 69;
begin
  insert into T_TEST(col01, col02) select n_num, column_value from table(tn_test);
end;
```

Resulting table would look something like this:

```
 col01 | col02
-------|-------
 69    | 10
 69    | 20
 69    | 30
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

[image: errors 6550, 642, 306]

What am I doing wrong? How to fix it? I could've done this in a `for` cycle, but isn't it too inefficient for required purpose?

Comment: You need to create the type at the database level (e.g. `create or replace type ...`) or use a pipelined function to return the contents of the collection.

Comment: What's wrong in creating a Type as boneist is suggesting? There's restriction to use local collections in `TABLE` functions which you might have understood. Simply create a nested table type and use it as you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong? How to fix it? I could've done this in a for
>   cycle, but isn't it too inefficient for required purpose?

If you inspect the error properly you could see the error. The error says:

> Local Collection Types are not allowed in SQL statement

Which means in your execution block:

> insert into T_TEST(col01, col02) select n_num, column_value from
>   table(tn_test);

Above statement is `NOT ALLOWED`.

Until Oracle 11g, you cannot use a `Type` declared under the scope if `PLSQL` block directly under `SQL` statement used inside the block. You need to change the scope of declaration of `Type` outside the `PLSQL` scope. Which means, you need to `REMOVE`

`type t_num is table of number;` from the package specification and create a `TYPE` outside the in `SQL` scope.

So you can do this:

```
Create or replace type t_num is table of number;
```

See below demo:

```
create table t_test (col01 number, col02 number);

-- Moving the type decalration under the scope of SQL.
Create or replace type t_num is table of number;

create or replace package p_test is
--  type t_num is table of number; --<-- Commenting the declaration since this is not allowed until 11g.
  function rtn(arg_tn t_num) 
    return t_num  PIPELINED;
end p_test;
/

create or replace package body p_test is
  function rtn(arg_tn t_num) 
    return t_num PIPELINED 
   is
    tn_row number;
  begin
    for i in arg_tn.first .. arg_tn.last
    loop
      tn_row := arg_tn(i);
      pipe row(tn_row);
    end loop;
    return;
  end;
end p_test;
```

Execution:

```
declare
  tn_test t_num := t_num(10, 20, 30);
  n_num   number := 69;
begin
  insert into T_TEST
    (col01,
     col02)
    select n_num,
           column_value
    from   table(tn_test);
    commit;
end;
```

Test:

```
 SQL> Select * from T_TEST;

     COL01      COL02
---------- ----------
        69         10
        69         20
        69         30
```

Answer (score 2):

The locally defined PL/SQL collection types cannot be used within a non-query DML statement (e.g. as an argument to a table function). Just move the initialization of the test data to the table function. Consider the following example:

```
create or replace package p_test is 
    type t_num is table of number;
    function rtn return t_num pipelined;
end p_test;
/
create or replace package body p_test is 
    function rtn return t_num pipelined is 
        tn_test t_num := t_num (10, 20, 30);
    begin 
        for i in 1..tn_test.count loop
            pipe row (tn_test (i));
        end loop;
        return;
    end;
end p_test;
/

begin
    insert into t_test (col01, col02) 
    select rownum, column_value from table (p_test.rtn ())
    ;
    dbms_output.put_line (sql%rowcount||' rows inserted.');  
end;
/
select * from t_test;     

3 rows inserted.

     COL01      COL02
---------- ----------
         1         10
         2         20
         3         30
```

If the arguments of the collection type are essential, use either the `FORALL` statement, or the SQL data types as suggested in the [@XING answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55951722/6571020).

Demo with the package as in the question without any change:

```
declare 
    sources p_test.t_num := p_test.t_num (10,20,30);
    targets p_test.t_num; 
    retrows p_test.t_num; 
    n_num number := 69;
begin
    select * bulk collect into targets
    from table (p_test.rtn (sources))
    ;
    forall i in indices of targets
    insert into t_test (col01, col02) values (n_num, targets (i)) 
    returning col01 bulk collect into retrows
    ;
    dbms_output.put_line (retrows.count||' rows inserted.'); 
end;
/

3 rows inserted.

select * from t_test;

     COL01      COL02
---------- ----------
        69         10
        69         20
        69         30
```

Answer (score 0):

Because there's a type mismatch for that `INSERT` statement among `col02` and `column_value`, which are of type `number` and `one-dimensional array`, respectively. If an iteration is applied to that array, the individual numbers are derived for each iteration step. It can be managed through use of a `cursor` :

```
declare
  tn_test p_test.t_num := p_test.t_num(10,20,30);
  n_num number := 69;
begin
  for c in ( select row_number() over (order by 0) rn, column_value from table(tn_test) t)
  loop
    insert into t_test(col01,col02) values(n_num, tn_test(c.rn));
  end loop;
end;
```

That way, you'll get

```
select * from t_test;

+------+------+
|col01 |col02 |
+------+------+
|  69  | 10   |
|  69  | 20   |
|  69  | 30   |
+------+------+
```

Comment: I've tried to implement a pipelined function approach and edited the question. Is your solution applicable to the new issue?